# IFTTT for offline use

Tags: windows, offline, productivity, scheduling

I am looking for a tool that would make my office life a bit easier. While I don't really like the online-ness of [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) (and I am not allowed to use it in the office anyway), from what I read and heard about IFTTT, that sounds much what I'm looking for.

E.g. I'd like

- if a file changes, pop up a notice
- if a file changes and certain content was found, play a sound
- if the screensaver starts, suspend the VMs and take a snapshot
- if I am away from keyboard for >5 minutes, run some unit tests (basically: run a program)
- every 20 minutes, remind me of drinking some water
- very minute, check the availability of servers and notify me if one is not available
- if my IP address changes, enable the firewall
- if I'm in the office before 8:00, do a HTTP request to wake up the server and start caching (haha, those pieces need a restart every night and are really slow if you access them the first time)
- ...

The program

- must run offline, i.e. is a local installation. As mentioned before, it should have some online features like HTTP, Ping etc.
- should cost <300 USD. If it is that expensive, it should be worth the money and really be a time saver.
- should be available as a perpetual personal license that allows being installed on a PC and laptop at the same time
- must work on Windows 7 SP1 x64 and Windows 10 x64, Windows 8 and 8.1 not necessarily required

I am not looking for a programming language suggestion. I know C# and I could implement all that myself if I just had the time. I also know Windows Task scheduler can run tasks at certain times.

I have tried:

- [Microsoft Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/), but it cannot react on file content changes, cannot react on IP address change, cannot determine the user idle time of the PC and does not provide an event system at all. Any event-like action needs to be modelled as an endless loop.

Comment: Did you find this program?
Or you wrote it yourself?

Comment: @AbolfazlRajabpour: I neither found one and I didn't implement it myself yet. Whenever I needed something similar, I used Autoit, Autohotkey or implemented a standalone C# program.

Comment: Not sure it can do all of that but have a look at [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Have you tried [Eventghost](http://www.eventghost.net/)? Not sure it does all you want but maybe worth having a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out **Ellp**

While it is not nearly as powerful and flexible as something like IFTTT, but it has the same promise, basically doing stuff based on other stuff.

It's free:
https://www.ellp.com/

Comment: The website is down. The tool seems no longer under active maintenance. The number of conditions is quite limited.